# Items in database sqlite are not updating (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms in visual studio and I have a list of products that I insert in a table. When I try to update the Cantidad, Precio or other feature, the Articulo don´t update and the list appears as it was before. I´m trying to use the PK as a string so when I try to update a item I need the Producto of the Articulo, it verify that the Id of the Producto exist in the database and then update.

This is my Model Articulo.cs

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Saansa.Modelos
{
    public class Articulo
    {
        [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Producto { get; set; }
        public int Precio { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string MasterCategory { get; set; }
        public string Category1 { get; set; }
        public string Category2 { get; set; }
        public string Category3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my xalm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Saansa"
             x:Class="Saansa.Inventario"
             Title="Inventario">

            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f5cda2">
                <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" HeightRequest="10" Source="inventario.png" ></Image>
                <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="Mi Cafe Delicias" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Large" TextColor="#b27b4b" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                <Entry x:Name="txtProducto" Placeholder="Código Producto"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtNombre" Placeholder="Nombre del producto"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtPrecio" Placeholder="Precio del producto"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtCantidad" Placeholder="Cantidad del Producto"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtMainCategory" Placeholder="Categoria general"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtSub1" Placeholder="Subcategoria 1"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtSub2" Placeholder="Subcategoria 2"></Entry>
                <Entry x:Name="txtSub3" Placeholder="Subcategoria 3"></Entry>
        <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" WidthRequest="200" Text="Añadir" Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#b27b4b" BorderWidth="3" CornerRadius="15"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnRead" WidthRequest="200" Text="Buscar" Clicked="BtnRead_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#b27b4b" BorderWidth="3" CornerRadius="15"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" WidthRequest="200" Text="Actualizar" Clicked="BtnUpdate_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#b27b4b" BorderWidth="3" CornerRadius="15"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDelete" WidthRequest="200" Text="Borrar" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#b27b4b" BorderWidth="3" CornerRadius="15"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="lstArticulo" BackgroundColor="#f5cda2">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Producto}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                           TextColor="Black"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In my Inventario.xalm.cs my update option is this:

```
 private async void BtnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProducto.Text))
            {
                Modelos.Articulo articulo = new Modelos.Articulo()
                {
                    Id = txtProducto.Text,
                    Producto = txtNombre.Text,
                    Precio = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrecio.Text),
                    Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text),
                    MasterCategory = txtMainCategory.Text,
                    Category1 = txtSub1.Text,
                    Category2 = txtSub2.Text,
                    Category3 = txtSub3.Text
                };

                //Update Person
                await App.SQLiteDb.SaveItemAsync(articulo);

                txtNombre.Text = string.Empty;
                txtCantidad.Text = string.Empty;
                txtProducto.Text = string.Empty;
                txtPrecio.Text = string.Empty;
                txtMainCategory.Text = string.Empty;
                txtSub1.Text = string.Empty;
                txtSub2.Text = string.Empty;
                txtSub3.Text = string.Empty;
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Updated Successfully", "OK");
                //Get All Persons
                var articuloLista = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
                if (articuloLista != null)
                {
                    lstArticulo.ItemsSource = articuloLista;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter Nombre articulo", "OK");
            }
        }
```

and my SQLiteHekper.cs:

```
public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Modelos.Articulo articulo)
        {   //articulo.Cantidad. !string.IsNullOrEmpty(articulo.Cantidad)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(articulo.Id))
            {
                //probando esto 
                //var nuevoArticulo = GetItemAsync(articulo.Producto);
                return db.UpdateAsync(articulo);
            }  
            else
            {
                return db.InsertAsync(articulo);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the return value of `db.UpdateAsync(...)`?

Comment: It has to be the column of the object with the new values that I just put except for its PK, but at the moment the return value does not work, its like the function does not update the columns.

Comment: it should return the number of rows that are updated.  If it returns 0 then there is a problem with the object you're passing

Comment: [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
        public string Id { get; set; } AutoIncrement for string won't work. You should be getting sql error.

Comment: That doesn't give me an error but I understand why you said that, the thing is that it does not search the table and find the PK. I change the PK  to be NotNull and it doesn´t wokr either. I try to use this tutorial: 
[link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-sqlite-database-crud-operations2/)
But here they use the PK as an int and i try to used it as an string. that is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that it was not getting the object, thats why first we need to call it and then edit the Articulo that we want to update.

```
Private async void BtnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text))
        {
            Modelos.Articulo articulo = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(txtNombre.Text);

            //Aparentemente dejar el texto vacío no es equivalente a "", por eso el +"0"
            articulo.Cantidad = (string.Equals("0", txtCantidad.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Cantidad : Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text);
            articulo.Category1 = (string.Equals("0", txtSub1.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Category1 : txtSub1.Text;
            articulo.Category2 = (string.Equals("0", txtSub2.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Category2 : txtSub2.Text;
            articulo.Category3 = (string.Equals("0", txtSub3.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Category3 : txtSub3.Text;
            articulo.MasterCategory = (string.Equals("0", txtMainCategory.Text + "0")) ? articulo.MasterCategory : txtMainCategory.Text;
            articulo.Precio = (string.Equals("0", txtPrecio.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Precio : Convert.ToInt32(txtPrecio.Text);
            articulo.Costo = (String.Equals("0", txtCosto.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Costo : Convert.ToInt32(txtCosto.Text);
            articulo.Producto = (string.Equals("0", txtProducto.Text + "0")) ? articulo.Producto : txtNombre.Text;

            await App.SQLiteDb.SaveItemAsync(articulo);

            txtNombre.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCantidad.Text = string.Empty;
            txtProducto.Text = string.Empty;
            txtCosto.Text = string.Empty;
            txtPrecio.Text = string.Empty;
            txtMainCategory.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSub1.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSub2.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSub3.Text = string.Empty;
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Producto actualizado con éxito", "OK");


        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter código articulo", "OK");
        }
    }
```

This makes to bring the object first, check if some data is not in the entry to let it be like it is and finally it updates the object.